# Is a turbulent burner chaotic system?

Tags: chaos-theory

This is a plot of temperature evolution with time of a specified flame zone of a highly turbulent combustion burner:

[Temperature vs Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p30SP.png)

- Blue (Lo) = temperature evolution at a "low" speed of inlet fuel
- Orange (Hi) = temperature evolution at a "high" speed of inlet fuel

The speed of the inlet fuel is part of the initial conditions.

**My question is: is this a chaotic or non-chaotic system?**

I know for a fact that Reynolds number is well above 30K (super turbulent) but I also see that this system "does not care" about the initial conditions - as long as there is ignition, the flame temperature always reaches around 2000 K, which makes sense. I also calculate the Largest Lyapunov exponent for this system and it is positive (close to 0) - indication of non-chaos.

So I am just trying to get my head around this as the system is super turbulent (chaotic) yet it is insensitive to the change in initial conditions? How do you interpret this correctly?

Comment: The flow of air may be chaotic while the temperature is not.

Comment: Okay, I see. And may I please ask your view on this: if I was to analyse the system at 5000 LTS (see figure), where the two different inlet fuel velocities result in very different temperatures - would you say that at 5000 LTS the system is chaotic in terms of temperature?

Comment: It's impossible to say from just two data points, but i suspect the answer is no. Ask yourself this question: if the LTS value changes by a little bit, can i use that change to predict how the temperature will change? Probably the answer is yes, and so as you mentioned in your question, the temperature of the system is not sensitive to this particular input.

Comment: I should add that I am not familiar with the particulars of your physical system, just the underlying theory of dynamical systems and chaos.